# NodeJS - Electron tray icon disappearing after a minute

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, trayicon

I have no idea what's going on, to be honest.

I've been keeping an eye to the icon and it just vanishes after a few minutes. No, it does not go to the arrow near the clock:

[image: Icon missing]

This is my icon showing up (the explosion in red):

[image]

I don't know how to debug if the icon is there but empty or if there's an event triggering it to hide, or if the tray process closes itself because of a bug. Nothing happens in the console or my app.

Could someone please help? Below is my whole `index.js`:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Tray, Menu} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

var win = '',
    iconpath = path.join(__dirname, '/libs/img/icon.ico');

// Create the browser window
function createWindow () {

  // BrowserWindow size
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 720,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  // tray menu
  var contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        label: 'Show app', click: function () {
            win.show()
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Quit', click: function () {
            app.isQuiting = true;
            app.quit();
        }
    }
  ]);

  // Creates tray menu with tray icon
  var appIcon = new Tray(iconpath);
  // Define menu
  appIcon.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

  win.on('close', function () {
    app.isQuiting = true;
    app.quit();
  });

  // Load the index.html of the app
  win.loadFile('./view/index.html');
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Answer (score 13):

This is a well-known problem related to garbage collection, mentioned in the [Electron FAQ](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq) page:

[My app's window/tray disappeared after a few minutes.](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#my-apps-windowtray-disappeared-after-a-few-minutes)

So, a quick fix is to move up the declaration of the `appIcon` variable out of the `createWindow` function, next to the `win` variable for instance:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Tray, Menu} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

var win = '',
    appIcon = null,
    iconpath = path.join(__dirname, '/libs/img/icon.ico');

// Create the browser window
function createWindow () {

  // BrowserWindow size
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 720,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  // tray menu
  var contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        label: 'Show app', click: function () {
            win.show()
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Quit', click: function () {
            app.isQuiting = true;
            app.quit();
        }
    }
  ]);

  // Creates tray menu with tray icon
  appIcon = new Tray(iconpath);
  // Define menu
  appIcon.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

  win.on('close', function () {
    app.isQuiting = true;
    app.quit();
  });

  // Load the index.html of the app
  win.loadFile('./view/index.html');
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Comment: It's is the correct answer, Thanks.

Comment: that is perfect answer thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, but I got the solution for this.
This happens when your `tray` variable which is used to store the tray gets garbage collected.

You can get rid of this just by making the variable global.

In your case create `appIcon` variable out of the `createWindow` function like this:

```js
let appIcon = null;
```

and then assign tray object like this:

```js
appIcon = new Tray(iconpath);
```

ref: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/faq#my-apps-tray-disappeared-after-a-few-minutes